# Using cut in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to recode a `for` loop into `dplyr` code that uses `cut`.  The error I get is :

> Error: 'breaks' are not unique

How can I make the `cut` function from the `for` loop the same in `dplyr`?

dput:

```
df <- structure(list(fyear = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 
1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 
1970, 1970, 1970), BEME = c(0.39713747645951, 0.548988782444936, 
0.537154930871343, 1.89357008340059, 1.66945262543448, 0.969181836638018, 
1.09989952916609, 0.858308443214104, 0.292175536881419, 0.684685677549708, 
0.338422675433708, 3.02671555788371, 0.422643864469658, 0.805317430736738, 
0.529954031556715, 0.617716486520065, 0.911576593365635, 0.4131850675139, 
1.16211278792693, 2.13177678851802), exchg = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 
19L, 11L, 11L, 11L)), .Names = c("fyear", "BEME", "exchg"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

`for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(fiscalyear)) {
  df$LMH[which(df$fyear==fiscalyear[i])] = cut(df$BEME[which(df$fyear==fiscalyear[i])],
        breaks=quantile(df$BEME[which(df$fyear==fiscalyear[i] & df$exchg==11)], c(0,0.3,0.7,1)),
        labels=F)
}

> head(df)
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]

  fyear      BEME exchg   LMH
  (dbl)     (dbl) (int) (int)
1  1970 0.3971375    11    NA
2  1970 0.5489888    11     2
3  1970 0.5371549    11     2
4  1970 1.8935701    11     3
5  1970 1.6694526    11     3
6  1970 0.9691818    11     2
```

`dplyr` code:

```
newdat <- df %>% 
  group_by(fyear) %>% 
  filter(exchg == 11) %>% 
  mutate(LMH = cut(df$BEME, breaks = quantile(df$BEME & df$exchg, c(0,0.3,0.7,1)), labels = FALSE))
```

Comment: in dplyr, using the `df$` notation bypasses `group_by` statements... Change `df$BEME` to just `BEME`. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with `BEME & exchg` inside the quantile function, this will return a boolean... I would remove the `& echg`, that seems to give the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the dplyr code, I think you want to replace

```
quantile(df$BEME & df$exchg, c(0,0.3,0.7,1))
```

with

```
quantile(BEME, c(0,0.3,0.7,1))
```

Final code:

```
newdat <- df %>% 
          group_by(fyear) %>% 
          filter(exchg == 11) %>% 
          mutate(LMH = cut(BEME, breaks = quantile(BEME, c(0,0.3,0.7,1)), labels = FALSE))
```